# Probability within probability

Tags: probability

Let $X_0 \sim Geom(1/2)$ and $X_k \sim Geom(p)$

Define $T=\min\{k \in \mathbb N | X_k > X_0\}$

Calculate $ET$.

I tried saying $ET=EET|X_0$, however I don't know how $T|X_0$ is distributed and I am stuck, anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that $X_0=n$, then each $X_k$ has probability $(1-p)^n$ of failing to be bigger than $X_0$, thus (assuming the $X_k$ are independent) $T$ is distributed geometrically with parameter $1-(1-p)^n$.

More precisely, $T$ is a discrete random variable and $X_0$ is a discrete random variable, so $E(T|X_0)$ here is simply a discrete random variable with

$$E(T|X_0)(n)=\sum_{t=0}^\infty tP(T=t|X_0=n)$$

Comment: Then assuming $T|X=n \sim Geom(1-(1-p)^n$, that defining $h(X)=ET|X$ would make $ET=Eh(X)=\sum \frac{p(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)^n}$ I can't seem to solve the sum